# How to introduce a new column in dynamo DB running in production?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-migration, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a use case where DynamoDB is running in production and I need to add a new column `IDUpdatedAt` which will also be serving as a sort key for one of the GSIs.
I tried a thing in test where my application adds the new rows with `IDUpdatedAt`, it's working fine but what about the existing rows? How to add the values for those?
Also the new rows will not be added without `IDUpdatedAt`, but how will the search be impacted for older rows?
PS: `IDUpdatedAt` is being used as a filter in the application, i.e., user can search for specific ID and can get results sorted by date. That's why `IDUpdatedAt` is also a part of GSI (sort key).
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea by adding the field to new items.  After all, DynamoDB does not enforce a particular schema outside of the primary key.

This also happens to be a very useful feature, especially when defining a GSI on that attribute; if the atttibute exists on the item, it ends up in the index!  For example, imagine modeling an email inbox in DDB where each item represents an email.  You could include an attribute 'is_read' and define a GSI using that atttibute.
If the 'is_read' attribute exists on the item, it's in the index.  Otherwise, it's not.  A cool way to use GSIs to implement filtering.
Pretty neat stuff!

However, there is no way to retroactively update all items with a new attribute other than manually updating each item (or in batches).  The equivalent in SQL databases is defining a new column.  Unfortunately, an analogous operation in DDB does not exist.